# Player dashes inconsistent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that I made with AI (or the AI made for me) that makes the palyer dash up, down, right and left when you swipe on the screen. It almost works as I expected it to work, but the only problem is that the player always dashes different distances, for example when I dash down and up again, im not in the same position as where i started.
Here the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 touchStartPos;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float dashSpeed = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            touchStartPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            Vector2 touchEndPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            Vector2 swipeDirection = touchEndPos - touchStartPos;
            if (swipeDirection.magnitude > 50f)
            {
                swipeDirection.Normalize();
                if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.x) > Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.y))
                {
                    swipeDirection.y = 0f;
                }
                else
                {
                    swipeDirection.x = 0f;
                }
                rb.velocity = swipeDirection * dashSpeed;
                StartCoroutine(DashCoroutine());
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator DashCoroutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5 / dashSpeed);
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

So my question is basically how do i fix this code so i always dash the same distance or if there is any better code (im pretty sure there is).
(BTW its a 2d top down game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: You might have another problem:

You are normalising before you remove one of the axis values

```
swipeDirection.Normalize();
if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.x) > Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.y))
    swipeDirection.y = 0f;
else
    swipeDirection.x = 0f;
```

Consider something like

V = (1.64,0.38)

Normalised will give (0.974191, 0.225727), then you'll zero that to

**(0.974191, 0.0)**

But if your vector is

V = (1.64,1.38)

Then it will be normalised to (0.765153, 0.643848) then zeroed to

**(0.765153, 0.0)**

You simply want a direction, so you need to normalise after zeroing a value.

```
if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.x) > Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.y))
    swipeDirection.y = 0f;
else
    swipeDirection.x = 0f;
swipeDirection.Normalize();
```

---

You might also be having problems with framerate dependant physics. If you're working with physics, you need to be using `FixedUpdate`, otherwise all of your physics work will be at the whim of your frame-rate. You do want to keep your input work in Update.

Something like this would work

```
Vector3? newDashVelocity = null
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        touchStartPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    }
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        Vector2 touchEndPos = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        Vector2 swipeDirection = touchEndPos - touchStartPos;
        if (swipeDirection.magnitude > 50f)
        {
            swipeDirection.Normalize();
            if (Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.x) > Mathf.Abs(swipeDirection.y))
            {
                swipeDirection.y = 0f;
            }
            else
            {
                swipeDirection.x = 0f;
            }
            newDashVelocity = swipeDirection * dashSpeed;
           
        }
    }
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // if there is no new dash velocity, do nothing
    if(!newDashVelocity.HasValue)
        return;

    rb.velocity = newDashVelocity.Value;

    newDashVelocity = null; // reset this so we don't apply it twice
    StartCoroutine(DashCoroutine()); // begin the coroutine
}
```

This will pass the new velocity to fixed update so it will only ever be applied once per fixed update

Then for your coroutine, you also want it tied as close as possible to fixed update

```
IEnumerator DashCoroutine()
{
    var waitTime = 5.f / dashSpeed;
    float elapsedTime = 0;
    while(elapsedTime < waitTime)
    {
        elapsedTime += Time.FixedDeltaTime;
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}
```

This should make your dash last a determined number of fixed update steps and keep it a lot more reliable.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your amazing answer, you really helped me out! It works now perfectly fine. Thank you for taking your time and putting so much effort in your answer!